# Sending SMS/email from SQL Server with queued users

Tags: sql-server

We need to send email/sms to users for notifying some changes in a table in the database.

There can be an issue of queuing.

So, we are thinking of using a windows service or SQL Server trigger.

1. Service can poll the database and send SMS / e-mail and delete notified rows
2. Send SMS/email and do same functionality from trigger

Your suggestions please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send message from SQL Server trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305637/send-message-from-sql-server-trigger)

Answer (score 1):

[Service broker?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166043%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

- Push the details onto a queue from the trigger (or stored proc?)
- Some process reads these and sends the email/sms. This can be separate from SQL Server